# OnsenUI pushPage doesn't load page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

Looks like I'm overseeing something. I just started with OnsenUI. I used the standard Tabbar Option and didn't really change anything in the . I have this in my index.html

```
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
         <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage("City1.html", options);">
        <ons-row>
          <ons-col>
            <header>
              <span class="item-title">City1</span>
            </header>
          </ons-col>
        </ons-row>                          
      </ons-list-item> </ons-navigator>
```

and I made a new template too:

```
  <ons-template id="City1.html">
<ons-navigator>
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left"><ons-toolbar-button ng-click="doSomething()"><ons-icon icon="ion-compose"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button></div>
      <div class="center">City1</div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </ons-toolbar>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

I want to slide into City1.html after clicking on City1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I think the main problem is that you are using " " twice in the same string, here:

```
ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage("City1.html", options);"
```

So City1.html is outside the actual string. Try with '':

```
ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('City1.html', options);"
```

Apart from that, you should close "ons-template" and put every "ons-list-item" inside an "ons-list". Besides, the "ons-navigator" in City1.html is not necessary. [Check this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rawrjQ).

You can read more information about these elements [here](http://onsen.io/guide/components.html). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I solved it with this:

```
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('City1.html', {
            animation: 'slide'
        });">
```

And putting  inside the ons-template tag of the Home view.